# How to add a header to a .csv file with csvfix

Tags: powershell, csv

I used csvfix to split a csv in multiple files, but now I don't have any header in these new files.

So I tried this :

```
csvfix echo -smq -hdr "zone,location,subject,start date" '.\myfile.csv' | Out-File -filepath '.\myfile.csv'
```

It doesn't work, myfile.csv contains only the header, all the original data are lost. I'm sure there is a good reason for that but I don't understand why.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there must be a way to achieve this with csvfix, but you posted a question here so here goes - a simple possible solution:

```
Get-Content .\myfile.csv | Set-Content .\temp.csv
"zone,location,subject,start date" | Set-Content .\myfile.csv
Get-Content .\temp.csv | Add-Content .\myfile.csv
```

Cheers!

Comment: I found another solution that split my csv file AND keep the header, but I still don't understand why my command line with csvfix doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, thinking just making a simple .csv file with just the header info in it and then using cat to join them.

i.e. something like cat file1.csv file2.csv >> file3.csv